# How to hide the apps created with Perl2Exe?

Tags: perl

How to hide the apps (running them in the background) created with Perl2Exe on Windows?
Or is there any other way to hide the apps written in Perl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For perl2exe, you need to pay for the full version.
Luckily, there are other options:
[Cava Packager](http://www.cava.co.uk/) is my favorite. It's free (as in beer) to use and seems to handle everything I throw at it, including Gtk2 applications.

[Par::Packager](http://par.perl.org/wiki/Main_Page) is a close second. It's free as in beer+speech and offers a -gui switch to suppress the terminal on launch. I don't like it as much because it seems to have a few problems resolving dependencies (especially .dll dependencies) and unlike Cava, it's a huge pain to work around this. It also seems to create much larger packages for some reason..
Oh and some might complain that par/pp is command-line while cava has a GUI.

Hope that helps.

Comment: How do I hide the application using Cava?

Comment: I assume you mean hiding the source code from the user? You can't, and Perl2Exe will not do this either. Cava will obfuscate your code (and shrink it a tiny bit), but it won't hide it.

edit: Oh I just read the other answer, maybe you didn't know how to turn off the console in cava. Yeah it's a setting in your project. Sorry if I misunderstood :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [exe_update.pl](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/exe_update.pl), It's what PAR/pp uses, but I'm not sure if that would violate  perl2exe license

Resolve dependencies yourself manually by

```
set path=
myPARppPackedProgram.exe
```

You'll get a popup window saying missing dll ..., then repackage your program while adding the missing dll with  `pp -l mydll.dll` , and repeat

If you have objdump (and/or you're not on windows), you can get a list of other dll's you need to pack with `objdump -p foo.dll |grep DLL.Name`

If you're using cava packager and want a gui program, choose "GUI Executable" for the "Executable Type" , see docs http://www.cavapackager.com/currentdoc/projecttree-executables.htm